# MySQL Availability Calendar

Tags: mysql, sql, calendar

I have a booking system and I want to display a **monthly** calendar view of a listing. I have the following table structure (with lots of other columns, as well);

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_calendar` (
    `dt` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`dt`)
);

CREATE TABLE `listings` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `listing_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `start_date` date NOT NULL,
    `end_date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

`sys_calendar` holds all dates from **2000-01-01** to **2040-12-31**;

```
dt
------------
2000-01-01
2000-01-02
2000-01-03
....
2040-12-30
2040-12-31
```

What I want to do is to display a monthly calendar for a specific listing. For example; I would like to display a calendar for `listing_id` = 10 at April 2013 (between 2013-04-01 and 2013-04-30 on `bookings` table).

```
dt         | Availability
-------------------------
2013-04-01 | No
2013-04-02 | No
2013-04-03 | Yes
2013-04-04 | Yes
2013-04-05 | Yes
2013-04-06 | Yes
....
2013-04-29 | No
2013-04-30 | Yes
```

I know that I have to join `sys_calendar` and `bookings` tables but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
SELECT  c.dt,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(b.id) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability
FROM    sys_calendar c
        LEFT JOIN bookings b
            ON b.Listing_id = 10
            AND c.dt BETWEEN b.Start_Date AND b.End_Date
GROUP BY c.dt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15f5e/1)**

Additionally if you wanted to display multiple availabilities you could use:

```
SELECT  c.dt,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN b.Listing_id = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability1,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN b.Listing_id = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability2,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN b.Listing_id = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability3,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN b.Listing_id = 4 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability4
FROM    sys_calendar c
        LEFT JOIN bookings b
            ON c.dt BETWEEN b.Start_Date AND b.End_Date
WHERE   c.dt BETWEEN '20130401' AND '20130430'
GROUP BY c.dt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15f5e/3)**

Comment: Thank you GarethD. Both queries work great but there is a tiny problem which effects the whole system. Based on your answer, I've rewritten the first query as `SELECT c.dt, CASE WHEN COUNT(b.id) > 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Availability FROM sys_calendar c LEFT JOIN bookings b ON b.listing_id = 16 AND c.dt >= b.start_date AND c.dt < b.end_date WHERE c.dt BETWEEN '20130401' AND '20130430' GROUP BY c.dt;`. Last day of the reservation must be marked as **available** because guest leaves the room before 12PM, so the room becomes available afternoon again. I think I forgot to tell this.